# Bootstrap tab-pane active class acting funny

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Tab pane is doing something really funky and I have been unsuccessful at tracing it down. Since it's rather difficult to explain, I'll just show you:

My HTML:

```
<div class = "col-md-12">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#overview" aria-controls="overview" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#newsletter" aria-controls="newsletter" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Newsletter</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#markets" aria-controls="markets" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Markets</a></li>
    </ul>

    <br />
      <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="overview">
            <p>
                Austin green juice health goth beard flannel marfa. Poutine everyday carry dreamcatcher gastropub fap banjo semiotics meditation, typewriter tacos disrupt. Fanny pack semiotics pug cray. Distillery food truck bespoke venmo, williamsburg austin jean shorts seitan intelligentsia mlkshk. Fashion axe vegan tumblr man braid, letterpress freegan master cleanse meditation. Typewriter biodiesel keytar four loko food truck knausgaard. Poutine umami pitchfork gentrify keytar fashion axe.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="newsletter">
            <h4>Monthly Newsletter</h4>
            <embed src="https://xx.s3.amazonaws.com/gbe-seasonal-xx.pdf" width="100%" height="500px" type='application/pdf'>
        </div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="markets">
            <center><div id = "holdGraph"></div>  </center>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

For reference, holdGraph is a display of graphs that I generate using a javascript library. They are pretty solid, and work other places so I'm inclined to believe they are not the problem.

Anyway, Back to the problem:

When the **"markets" tab-pane is active**, the content displays as it should:
[image]

BUT, when the **"markets" tab-pane is NOT active**, the graph displays as follows:
[image]

**My question**: has anyone ever experienced this before? if so, how did you fix it?

Comment: It seems to be something related to the bootstrap screen size preferences. I just experienced something like it, In my case I've customized the media (min-width: ...) { (...) } and media (max-width: ...) { (...) } things. Did you tried that?

Comment: @GetApp - what do you mean? Do you have a fiddle of some sort I can look at?

Comment: It may also be worth mentioning that the **NON ACTIVE** defaults to a width of 600px

Comment: I mean the behavior of the bootstrap classes involved with and withour active tag or screen changes. I checked my bootstrap lib and I noticed that col-md-12 has a little change when screen is min-width = 992px, for example. It could be related to the problem.

Comment: Not sure if you actually care or not, but as you seem to have wanted to hide info in your screenshots (and changed the overview text), you should know that your email newsletter preview is included in the code snippet you provided.

Comment: @gravityplanx - good eye

Comment: @GetApp can you provide the css you used?

Comment: I wish someone had an answer to this.